# Add forms to a locked down Drupal distribution

Tags: forms, drupal

We are currently using a third party Drupal distribution that is locked down due to contractual agreement.

What is the best way for us to add forms to our site that will post to a web service?

Options we considered are:

- Deploy another open distribution (core) that we can add forms to and link from the third party site.
- Paying the vendor to create the form for us on that distribution (expensive, long lead time).

Any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without actually knowing the details of your contractual agreement.

With drupal a distribution is a set of modules and configuration that lies in the profiles subdirectory of your drupal file system.

So you can add additional modules outside of that by adding them to the sites/all/modules directory.

That way they are not actually part of the distribution but you can still use them.

So for example you can add a custom module that has the forms & web service posting to sites/all/modules and it won't impact the distribution at all.

However if your contract says something like you cannot modify your drupal site/configuration at all then I think you're pretty stuck in a crappy contract.

If you are in a contract where it is expensive & takes a long time to do something that sounds relatively straight forward (again I don't know the details but a form that submits to a web service is generally pretty straight forward) but you aren't allowed to go outside of them to do the work you're in trouble.

Deploying another site just for a form or a couple of forms doesn't really sound like a good idea.

If they belong on the existing site they should be part of the existing site.

If the contract really does exclude you from adding your own code to the site at all it comes down to discussing it with your website provider.

Surely if you aren't allowed to modify the site then there should be a clause that covers you in the case that they don't complete work in a timely fashion.